# Deciding between slow beta sites and Stack Overflow

Tags: support, beta-sites

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160095/difference-between-returning-false-or-true-first). I think it was probably a better fit for the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but for the reasons I cited in my question, I posted it on SO.

> I deliberated whether to post this on code review or here. I came to
>   the conclusion that it is a straightforward question about PHP and
>   with the number of supporters here, it would likely get an answer, as
>   code review is slow and the question has a greater chance of not being
>   answered.

The answers and feedback have been amazing and, I believe, will add another good resource for visitors to the site.

I have attempted to be active on the Code Review SE, but there is not a great deal of interaction.

Can anyone suggest a way to support our Beta sites and yet still get good answers?

Comment: So there's not a great deal of activity, and when you get a question that would be on topic there you post it elsewhere? How's that going to help, you know, getting activity there?

Comment: Code Review is actually quite a healthy beta it seems. It can't compete with SO, true, but are you in that much of a hurry to get an answer?

Comment: @Mat see my question " as code review is slow and the question has a greater chance of not being answered. ? I would be lucky to get one answer over the next few days

Comment: @Skippy How is withholding content going to improve that situation though?

Comment: @Bart yes my assignment is due tomorrow, and it doesn't get many responses there

Comment: @bart, you're answering my question with questions.. so is Mat.. these are all questions I ask myself..

Comment: Is a conundrum, which is why I asked the question..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest a way to support our Beta sites and yet still get good answers?

Sure. Post your questions there. Any Q&A, especially in a beta stage, lives or dies by its content. Without questions, there are no answers. Without questions, there will be no participation. So if you're looking to support a beta site, post good on-topic questions. And while you're at it, try to find something you can answer.

Sometimes there is an overlap between sites, and your posts might fit on a well-established site and on a beta site. (This is a rare case though. Make sure it is really true.) If that is the case, what should you do? True, we all think that our questions are very important and need to be answered immediately. But is that really the case? If there is any possibility at all that your question is not as urgent as you think, I'd argue you should post on the beta site. Give them a chance.

And why not promote your question after posting it? Know people in your social circle that might be able to answer it? Give them the link to your question. Share it on Twitter, [Friendface](http://theitcrowd.wikia.com/wiki/Friendface), or whatever other appropriate channel you can think of. You might end up driving some extra traffic there.

There is nothing wrong with posting it on an active graduated site if it's equally on topic there. But with regards to supporting beta sites you think deserve a chance, I wouldn't do it if I weren't in a hurry.

Comment: I like your idea about posting links for people to answer it.. didn't think of that... as for answering questions there.. em.. better if I don't just yet.. it would drag down the site quality.. and yes.. if not in a hurry.. one can wait.. sometimes one cannot cheers and thnx for answer

Comment: Were those edits really necessary @cody? Was it incorrect before?

Comment: No, the only necessary one was that missing period. I just couldn't leave well enough alone after that. :-)

Comment: Ah okay. :) No problem. I was just wondering. It's not my first language after all.

Comment: Oh really? Wow, I always assumed you were, just living in Switzerland. You speak nearly impeccable English for it not being your first language.

Comment: Well thank you @CodyGray :) I'm am actually Dutch. So not Swiss either.

Comment: I assume the Dutch teach English from an early age like Germany, Norway, Sweden, etc.? I've always been impressed at how well so many Northern Europeans speak English. Languages are not really my thing. I can fake my way through basic German and Norwegian after several years of college courses, but that's about it.

Answer (score 7):

> Can anyone suggest a way to support our Beta sites and yet still get good answers?

There are several things you can do.

- In addition to posting your questions on a Beta site, you can *answer* questions there as well.  Code Review currently has [over 1000 unanswered questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
- Since you'll get an account association bonus, you'll be able to vote (just up to begin with) for good questions and answers.
- Edit questions and answers that can be improved.  Anyone can suggest an edit, and you'll gain 2 reputation points for every substantial edit that gets approved.

Comment: all good, unless you are a learner and can't answer the questions :)